# getting 0 values inside my array from getdocument which insdie getdocuments

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

iam working with firestore  i have two structs 
one called history 
aother called cart 
simply hisory struct is

```
struct UserOrderHistoryModel {
    var id : String? = ""
    var dateOrderCreated : String? = ""
    var cartArray : [CartItemModel]
}

struct CartItemModel {
    var id : String? = ""
    var restaurantImageUrl : String
    var restaurantTitle : String
    var menuItemImageUrl : String
    var menuItemTitle : String
    var countOfMenuItemSelected : Int
}
```

what i am trying to do is load history so i use getdocument to get the id and the date

i wanted to get order collection which inside history document 
so i use another getdocuments inside  the first one

```
func loadUserOrderHistory(completion : @escaping (_ error :Error? ,_ userHistoryArray : [UserOrderHistoryModel]?) -> ()) {

    var historyArray = [UserOrderHistoryModel]()


    let userHistoryRef = USERS.document(UserConfigurations.currentUserID!).collection("history")

    userHistoryRef.getDocuments { (snapShots, error) in

        if error != nil {
              completion(error , nil)
        }else {

            historyArray.removeAll()

            for document in snapShots!.documents {

                let historyId = document.documentID
                let historyData = document.data()
                let historyDate = historyData["date_order_created"] as? Timestamp ?? nil

                let historyDateToString = String(describing: historyDate?.dateValue())

                var orderArray = [CartItemModel]()

                self.loadUserHistoryOrders(histroyDocumentReference: userHistoryRef.document(historyId), completion: { (error, cartArray) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                    }else {
                        orderArray = cartArray!
                    }

                })

                let userHistory = UserOrderHistoryModel(id: historyId, dateOrderCreated: historyDateToString , cartArray: self.orderArray)

                historyArray.append(userHistory)

            }

            completion(nil , historyArray)
        }
    }

}


private  func loadUserHistoryOrders( histroyDocumentReference : DocumentReference, completion : @escaping (_ error : Error? ,_ historyOrders : [CartItemModel]? ) -> ())  {

var cartArray = [CartItemModel]()

histroyDocumentReference.collection("orders").getDocuments  { (snapShot, error) in
    if error != nil {
        completion(error,nil)
    }else {

        for document in snapShot!.documents {

            let id = document.documentID

            let cartDictionary = document.data()

            let restaurantImageUrl = cartDictionary["restaurant_imageurl"] as? String ?? "none"
            let restaurantName = cartDictionary["restaurant_title"] as? String ?? "none"
            let menuItemImageUrl = cartDictionary["menuItem_imageurl"] as? String ?? "none"
            let menuItemName = cartDictionary["menuItem_title"] as? String ?? "none"
            let count = cartDictionary["number_of_selected_menuitem"] as? Int ?? 0

            let cart = CartItemModel(id: id, restaurantImageUrl: restaurantImageUrl, restaurantTitle: restaurantName, menuItemImageUrl: menuItemImageUrl, menuItemTitle: menuItemName, countOfMenuItemSelected: count)

            cartArray.append(cart)
        }

        completion(nil , cartArray)
    }
  }
}
```

so orderArray inside second getdocumnet which i put it inside another function called loadUserHistoryOrders

i debugged the code and found that
once i get to end of the this function orderArray is back to 0 values

here is the pics of my firestore

url of pics : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NX8NIUN2Yb9m3_7A8EnZgAxWe8xuhNDh

Update : 
i solved the problem by adding completion of loadUserOrderHistory  inside the call of the second method  loadUserHistoryOrders

```
    func loadUserOrderHistory(completion : @escaping (_ error :Error? ,_ userHistoryArray : [UserOrderHistoryModel]?) -> ()) {

    var historyArray = [UserOrderHistoryModel]()


    let userHistoryRef = USERS.document(UserConfigurations.currentUserID!).collection("history")

    userHistoryRef.getDocuments { (snapShots, error) in

        if error != nil {
              completion(error , nil)
        }else {

            historyArray.removeAll()

            for document in snapShots!.documents {

                let historyId = document.documentID
                let historyData = document.data()
                let historyDate = historyData["date_order_created"] as? Timestamp ?? nil

                let historyDateToString = String(describing: historyDate?.dateValue())

                var orderArray = [CartItemModel]()

                self.loadUserHistoryOrders(histroyDocumentReference: userHistoryRef.document(historyId), completion: { (error, cartArray) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                    }else {
                        orderArray = cartArray!

                       let userHistory = UserOrderHistoryModel(id: historyId, dateOrderCreated: historyDateToString , cartArray: self.orderArray)

                       historyArray.append(userHistory)

                       completion(nil , historyArray)

                    }

                })



            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Pics of firestore?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: ok i solved the problem by the way but i show pics and the solution to help others